# PFFile image not loaded before attaching to PFImageView?

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, pffile

I'm using Parse with Facebook login to create a new user. I get a few fields from Facebook like their name and location, request their profile image to load in the background before I segue to my main view controller which has a PFImageView for the profile image.

The problem is that the PFFile user[@"profileImage"] is still nil by the time the main view controller's viewDidLoad fires, so there's nothing to loadInBackground.

I don't want to wait for the profile image to load before going to the main view controller...that would take some random time and just be bad.

So, how to I deal with a PFFile that hasn't loaded before I give it to the PFFImageView? Some kind of placeholder?

Here's my code:

```
------- in LoginViewController.m

- (void) pressedFacebookLogin {
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions...
        if(user.isNew) {
           FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
           [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;    

                user[@"fullName"] = userData[@"name"];
                // get location, relationship if available
                [user saveInBackground];

                // start getting the user's profile image before going to main view controller
                NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]];
                NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pictureURL];
                [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

                    if (connectionError == nil && data != nil) {
                        UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(tmpImage);
                        PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"image.png" data:imageData];
                        user[@"profileImage"] = imageFile;
                        [user saveInBackground];
                    }
                }];

                [self segueToMainViewController];

           }];
        }else {
             // deal with existing user...
        }
    }];
}

-------------- in MainViewController.m

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

    self.profileImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"];
    PFFile *profileImageFile = user[@"profileImage"];
    // at this point profileImageFile is nil
    self.profileImageView.file = profileImageFile;
    [self.profileImageView loadInBackground];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the place where you get the profileImageFile as empty add this line.

I guess the profileImageView you use is a ImageView.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *profileImageView;

// at this line where you get profileImageFile as nil
[self.profileImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:user[@"profileImage"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_profileImage"]];
```

Comment: No, the profileImageView is a PFImageView, a subclass of UIImageView from Parse that, given a PFFile, can load it's image file in the background. That's the whole point...because I'm creating a user for the first time and their profile image hasn't been downloaded from Facebook yet, user[@"profileImage"] is nil when I get to viewDidLoad in the next viewController. It eventually does get filled in, but it's too late for viewDidLoad.